# Failed to set up scaling socket server with cluster with expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have been trying to follow the instructions from the official documentation of socket.io on how to use multiple nodes with the Node.js cluster module, but I have not been able to make it work properly. The client-side application is unable to retrieve the data from the server-side because of the cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) issue. I am wondering what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this problem.
Here my setup:

```
const app: Express = express();

if (cluster.isPrimary) {
  app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "10mb" }));
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", `${process.env.URL_CLIENT}`);
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
      "GET,PUT,POST,PATCH,DELETE,UPDATE,OPTIONS"
    );
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    next();
  });
  app.use(helmet());
  app.use(morgan("dev"));
  const excludePaths = [/^\/products\/(.*)/, /^\/authen\/(.*)/, "/products"];
  app.use(authMiddleware.unless({ path: excludePaths }));
  app.use(express.static(dirPath));
  // route handling
  app.use("/authen", authenRouter);
  .....
  // error handling
  app.use(ErrorFunction);

  console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);
  const httpServer = createServer(app);
  // app.use(cors(corsOptions));
  //mongo running
  mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
  connect();
  async function connect() {
    try {
      await mongoose.connect(MONGO_URL as string);
      console.log("mongoDB connected");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
  setupMaster(httpServer, {
    loadBalancingMethod: "least-connection",
  });
  setupPrimary();
  cluster.setupPrimary({
    serialization: "advanced",
  });

  // mongo after initiated
  mongoose.connection.on("error", (err) => {
    console.error("MongoDB connection error:", err);
  });
  mongoose.connection.on("disconnected", () => {
    console.log("mongoDB disconnected");
  });
  //excluded paths
  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
  httpServer.listen(PORT, () =>
    console.log(`server listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`)
  );
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
  cluster.on("exit", (worker) => {
    console.log(`Worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
    cluster.fork();
  });
} else {
  console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);
  const httpServer = createServer(app);
  const io = new Server<
    ClientToServerEvents,
    ServerToClientEvents,
    InterServerEvents,
    SocketData
  >(httpServer, {
    cors: { origin: `${process.env.URL_CLIENT}`, credentials: true },
  });
  io.adapter(createAdapter());
  setupWorker(io);
  io.use(socketMiddleware);
  io.on("connection", async (socket) => {
    handleConnection(socket);
    handlePrivateMessage(socket, io);
    handleTyping(socket);
    handleNewMessageCheck(socket);
    handleDisconnection(socket, io);
  });
}
```